# why Syntax error: missing ) in JSON string built with StringBuilder

Tags: asp.net, json, stringbuilder

my string builder to create JSON Reply :

```
List<string> aList = getList();
StringBuilder StrBuilder = new StringBuilder();
StrBuilder.Append("\"length\":\"");
StrBuilder.Append(aList.Count.ToString());
int i = 1;
foreach (string str in aList)
{
   StrBuilder.Append("\", \"File" + i + "\":\"");
   StrBuilder.Append(str.ToString());
   i++;
}
```

I don't know where the error is but I got the following error :

[image: JSON - ")" missing error]

Comment: JSON uses curly brackets: `{}` instead of `()`

Comment: That error message is a bit misleading.

Comment: I highly encourage you to use something like [JSONWriter](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONWriter.html) instead of building JSON strings manually.

Comment: Go to json.org and study the JSON syntax.  It only takes 5-10 minutes to learn.

Comment: And that's not the right way to create a list.  It should be a JSON *array*, not a JSON *object*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
List<string> aList = getList();
StringBuilder StrBuilder = new StringBuilder();
StrBuilder.Append("{\"length\":\"");
StrBuilder.Append(aList.Count.ToString());
int i = 1;
foreach (string str in aList)
{
   StrBuilder.Append("\", \"File" + i + "\":\"");
   StrBuilder.Append(str.ToString());
   i++;
}
StrBuilder.Append("\"}");
```

It needs closing " and needs to add { }.